# QR code for calendar event in php

Tags: php, events, calendar, qr-code

I have used the code found on [this page](http://webcodingeasy.com/PHP-classes/QR-code-generator-class) to generate QR codes.

I want to generate a QR code for calendar event. I tried using this function:

```
function calendar_event($summary, $dtstart, $dtend){
    $this->data = "BEGIN:VEVENT:SUMMARY:" . $summary . ";dtstart:" . $dtstart . ";dtend:" . $dtend . ";END:VEVENT;"; 
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Could anyone help me?

Comment: What is not working? What the problem? This snippet shows nothing except string (_data_) which should be encoded in QR.

Comment: I think that the 
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Test Meeting
DTSTART:20110713T190000Z
DTEND:20110713T200000Z
END:VEVENT encodes them automatically.

Comment: **QR code** is not generating or something wrong when you **scan** it?

Comment: When i scan it, it is supposed to add an event to the calendar. But it reads it as text.

Comment: It is normal behavior, actually. If you scan QR code it contains _only_ data encoded in it (_text_). If you want to do smth. with this data you should have parser for it. The text encoded in QR is common format for calendar data exchange. But to be able to add event to calendar you should scan it with proper application that is able to **understand this format** and **work with calendar**. So usual QR scanners will **only decode the QR itself**.

Comment: But when i create a calendar event in an online generator, the mobile reads it fine.

Comment: Thus, create **2 identical events**, encode them and **read** both QR codes **as plain text** **and compare** them to see the difference. Probably you will notice something odd if it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `\n`. And you should not use `;`, but `:` in terms of a key-value pair.

This is working for me: `BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nDTSTART:20110422\nDTEND:20110422\nSUMMARY:Karfreitag\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR`

Answer (score 0):

Complete code can be

> BEGIN:VEVENT\nSUMMARY:My+Event\nDESCRIPTION:Description\nLOCATION:Location\nDTSTART:20200225T114509Z\nDTEND:20210225T114509Z\nEND:VEVENT